Почему в питоне нет фигурных скобок а в других языках есть?
Почему в питоне нет фигурных скобок а в других языках есть???

Да в Питоне и точки с запятой после оператора нет.


А что вы там такое интересное пишите с отступами? - Шшшшш, - ответил Гвидо Ван Россум. Так и родилось название нового языка программирования - Питон. Было это 36 лет наза, в далёком 1989 году - году Змеи. :-)


Почему в других языках есть фигурные скобки? Потому что нужно каким-то образом структурировать код, разбивать его на блоки. Кстати, фигурные скобки - это не единственный способ структурировать код. Бывают просто скобки - LISP, бывают ключевые слова - Паскаль, Ада, bash, а бывают шибко замороченные правила - Smalltalk, Haskell.
Создатель пайтона Гвидо ван Россум заметил, что несмотря на наличие синтаксических средств для структурирования кода, во всех разумных программах блоки выделяются также отступами.
При создании Пайтона он решил: давайте оставим что-нибудь одно, или скобки, или отступы. Без отступов код становится нечитаемым поэтому оставили отступы.
Вот интервью создателем языка, Гвидо Ван Россумом. Самый первый вопрос: почему отступы.
https://youtu.be/GQf25_9NOts?si=8StQldq-P-OanCst

А почему точки с запятой после оператора нет? Шо там Гвидон сказал на этот счёт? :-)

@rotabor, а зачем? И так понятно, когда строка заканчивается. Единственный случай, когда нужна была бы возможность разбивать одну строку на несколько - это fluent интерфейс, но это не очень идиоматичный вид кода для Python (для таких редких случаев приходится все в общие скобки оборачивать).

@rotabor Про точки с запятой Гвидо сказал, что одна строка - одна операция. Поэтому тчк-зпт становится избыточным. В этом Пайтон не одинок. Такое встречается сплошь и рядом в скриптовых языках. Из мэйнстримовых такое есть в Golang. NB: строка в Пайтоне - это не строка текста, а logical line of code, поэтому можно разбивать вызов функции или конструктур списков на несколько строк. NB2: точка в запятой в Пайтоне таки есть. Можно записать несколько инструкций в одну строку, разделив ';. Но это вот прям фу-фу-фу ))

Именно отсутствие скобочек постоянно останавливает меня от использования питона

@avp, вы теряете отличный, выразительный инструмент. Для меня Питон, язык на котором идеи воплощаются быстрее всего. Странно отказываться от инструмента из-за внешнего вида кода.

@StanislavVolodarskiy, конечно, на самом деле скобочки это отговорка, чтобы не учить его всерьез. Реально он понравился мне давно, тут в основе те же идеи, что были предложены в setl. Просто чую, что уже не запомню все богатство языка и вместо написания кода буду постоянно что-то гуглить и экспериментировать (вот сейчас, после вашего комментария, полазил и обнаружил, что на питоне, например, вполне можно модифицировать разные типы в структурах двоичного файла (вполне себе, такая, сишная задача)). Ну, подумаю еще, может созрею попробовать что-то из практических инструментов на нем сваять ...

@avp Ruby!

@rotabor, выглядит привлекательно. Но как только задумаешься о работе с двоичными данными (elf или чего-то в этом духе), то (как и в случае с питоном) понимаешь, что никакого преимущества (даже просто удобства программирования) по сравнению с Си тут нет

@avp Не как альтернатива C, но как альтернатива Python.
